# Can't connect to other computers on wireless network with Belkin N150

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I recently switched to a Belkin N150 wireless router, and I can no longer connect to other machines on my wireless network. Whenever I try to ping or ssh to another laptop on the network, it just hangs. Additionally, if I start a web server my laptop, I can't access it from any other machine (phones included). Similarly to ssh, they just hang while trying to load it.

Before this router I had an older Airport Extreme, and I did not have any issues connecting to other machines.

**Why can't I connect to other machines?**

Things I've tried:

- Connecting either via IP or .local
- Switching ports for the HTTP server (and using `0.0.0.0` as the hostname)
- Checking the router logs to ensure that I'm hitting the correct IP's
- ssh'ing or loading the webpage on the computer serving it up (to ensure that I've got the correct port/IP address)
- [`arp(8)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/arp.8.html)'ing the other host with `arp <other ip>` — I get `(incomplete)` for the link layer address
- `arp -l -a` — `(incomplete)` for the other machines' link layer addresses
- `sudo arp -d -a` — still doesn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

I updated the firmware and this is all working now. `~*facepalm*~`

It's an N150 V1, so I downloaded the 1.00.13 version firmware from Belkin's [skeezy, not-https firmware updates page](http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?articleNum=4815), so I'm probably getting hacked rn. Oh wait, the page title says "official," I'm sure it's cool.